# Asp.net SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: sql, asp.net, plesk

I have a web application in asp.net 4.6.1 I do not have a custom membership and role providers but just a simple Login functionality. When i open the app homepage in it connects to the database and retrieves some information. There is also a login form and when i login it validates the user through the database and redirects me to the reserved pages but than this error appears:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This error is only thrown on the server(Godaddy, plesk). In my local machine it works fine. Even on the server/ Godaddy/plesk there are functionalities working fine with the database, It is only the Login page that throws this error.

My connection string looks like this

```
<add name="connetionString" connectionString="Data Source=174.168.47.21;Integrated Security=False;User ID=admin2020;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Password=cyber2020;" />
<!--<add name="connetionString/local" connectionString="Server=LAPTOP-HM20U6J6\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ArmourCyberSecurity;Trusted_Connection=True;" />-->
```

Kindly help with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing the database instance and possibly port on your connection string?

Comment: Try to enter  "174.168.47.21" in your sql server login screen with credentials. If you able to login, then your code must be correct. But I think  you are missing something in the connection string.

Comment: @mattbloke my connection string is fine because it is working for the other parts of the website where the db is being accessed and the data is populated. It is just in the login screen that this error is thrown. database operations are working fine on the other screens.

Comment: @VishalPawar i tried adding the port number although it was not required. Adding that gives an error in the connection string. Done that. It dosen't work

Comment: You don't specify a database either in the connection string. I'm surprised it works in any scenario.I think its worth trying different connection strings to see if that is your problem since the error suggests that its some kind of connection problem.

Comment: Sry for the late reply but the issue got resolved. The error was that the App_Data folder was not getting published with the project which was casing the error in the Login functionality because that folder contains some mdf file required for the in built windows form Login functionality.
To answer your doubt @mattbloke the data sourse itself is the ip address to the database so a database name is not required.